# How to obtain the (weighted or unweighted) L1 imbalance measure for "raw" data

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, matching, mahalanobis

I have two questions regarding the JASA paper, *Multivariate Matching Methods That Are Monotonic Imbalance Bounding*, by Iacus et al. (2011), the authors produce Figure 2 (left panel) where they compare the L1 measure for propensity score, mahalanobis and cem matching methods and benchmark against the L1 measure for the "raw" data. In their supplementary materials they state "file acompleteone.R: produces Figures 2 and 3 and Table 3" but no such file exists in their directory. Having read the paper and the preceding paragraphs before Figure 2 carefully, I'm still not understanding how they calculate L1(H) for the "raw" data.

I believe that for each of the 250 iterations, they randomly select an upper and lower limit for the coarsening range of each variable and then select H randomly as opposed to their rule-of-thumb median method but it appears this is the case only for the raw, propensity score and mahalanobis methods as for cem they state, "we use CEM with fixed coarsening (10 intervals for each continuous variable and no coarsening for the categorical variables)".

Additionally, it is not 100% clear to me whether they calculate the weighted or unweighted L1 imbalance measure, although [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/cem/man/L1.profile.html) it appears it is weighted but no mention of this in the actual paper. If weights are used for the paper's Figure 2 results, any idea why weights are not explicitly in the formula for their L1 multivariate imbalance measure? (Formula (6))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that binning has two roles in the CEM literature: 1) defining the bins used to coarsen the covariates for CEM and 2) defining the bins for calculation of the L1 statistic. In this paper, they choose a single binning strategy for performing CEM (10 bins for continuous variables and no binning for categorical variables) and 250 binning strategies for calculation of the L1 profile. If they used the same binning strategy to calculate the L1 statistic as they did for CEM, the L1 statistic would be equal to zero by construction.

The way the compute the L1 statistic for the raw data is simply by implementing a binning strategy (i.e., coarsening covariates using one set of bin definitions), and within each bin, the compute the difference in the relative frequency of treated and control units, then compute the sum of those absolute differences. For all other matching methods, they use the same bins as in the raw data but compute the relative frequencies as weighted relative frequencies using the resulting matching weights. They do this same method for 250 binning strategies. Note that they only do the matching once per method: one round of PS matching, one round of Mahalanobis distance matching, and one round of CEM using the CEM binning strategy above. From each of these methods, they extract one set of weights, and then they apply those weights to the 250 binning strategies to compute the L1 profiles.

They do not describe how they randomly draw binnings. In the R package `cem`,  which was developed by the authors, for each continuous variable, a number between 2 and 12 is drawn to select the number of bins that variable will have. All categorical variables are not coarsened at all. In the R package `cobalt`, which I developed, the same strategy is used for continuous variables but categorical variables are also randomly collapsed; this works by choosing a number of bins and randomly assigning categories into those bins.

To compute the weighted L1 statistic, they compute the weighted relative frequencies using the weights. I agree that the paper could have been more explicit about how this was done. First, they divide the weights in each treatment group by their sum. Then, for some combination of covariates $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x}'$, they compute the sum of the weights of the treated units with $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x}'$ and the sum of the weights of the control units with $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x}'$. Using the formula in the paper, we could have
\begin{align}
f_{\mathbf{x}'}&=\sum_{i:\mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{x}'}{I(T_i=1)w^*_i} \\
g_{\mathbf{x}'}&=\sum_{i:\mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{x}'}{I(T_i=0)w^*_i}
\end{align}
where $I(.)$ is the indicator function, $w^*_i = w_i / \sum_j{I(T_j=T_i)}w_j$ and $w_i$ is the matching weight for unit $i$. Prior to matching, $w_i=1$ for all $i$, and that is how the unweighted L1 statistic is computed.

Comment: Thank you @Noah for the great explanation. Let me recap to see if I understand correctly, this means bins_cem is fixed at 10 to coarsen covariates, but the bins_iteration is a random draw from say [2,12]. The L1 raw is unweighted L1, the PS and MD L1s are weighted L1s based on bins_iteration and the CEM L1 is using CEM weights based on bins_cem, but calculated on data coarsened according to bins_iteration.

Comment: I have one follow up question regarding weighted L1 vs unweighted L1. As the PS and MD matching have trimmed the dataset to 2 times the number of treated, wouldn't it make sense to calculate the unweighted L1s from these matching methods? Especially if we aren't interested in using PS or MD weights in subsequent regressions. Also, for raw unweighted L1, this is CEM without the weights. My first thought would be to compare "raw" L1 vs the unweighted L1s from PS and MD but in a way interpret the "raw" L1 as a CEM like approach whereas we know CEM + weights will always produce L1=0. Any thoughts?